# Receive params and save in other model and remove error Couldn't find Authorization with 'id'= 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, relationship

I have a view with checkboxes and input text.
I checked one checkbox and digit value on input, after submit. But have two problem... A error on params and don't save the values on my table, this is my code:

refinancings_controller.rb

```
  def new
    if params[:authorization]
      @selected_ids = params[:authorization][:contract_ids]
      @authorizations = Authorization.where("contract_number in (?)", @selected_ids)
    end
    @employee = Employee.search_cpf(params[:search_employee_by_cpf])
    @refinancing = Refinancing.new
    params[:authorization][:contract_ids].each_with_index do |id, index|
      Authorization.find(id).update_column(value_solve: params[:authorization][:value_solve], situation: 2)
    end
  end
```

This is my console:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search_employee_by_cpf"=>"123456789", "authorization"=>{"contract_ids"=>["11"], "value_solve"=>["334545", "", ""]}, "commit"=>"Reserve"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 18ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

And the error is:

```
Couldn't find Authorization with 'id'= 0
```

My view is correct. Other thing. Refinancing belongs_to :authorization and Authorizarion has_many :refinancings
When I checked, the id of checkboxes clicked pass ok and the value_solve too, but the situation don't change and nothing save on db

Comment: Why not ```Authorization.where(id: params[:authorization][:contract_ids]).update_all(value_solve: params[:authorization][:value_solve], situation: 2)``` so it's a single insertion instead of n insertions? Plus this won't attempt to update records where the id doesn't exist.

Comment: Because I receive this error ever: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer this is:

```
      auth_params = params[:authorization]
auth_params[:contract_number].zip(auth_params[:value_solve].reject(&:blank?)).each do |contract_number, value_solve|
          Authorization.where(contract_number: contract_number).update_all(value_solve: value_solve, situation: 2)
      end
```

:D

Answer (score 0):

You should just be using each instead of each_with_index. The way you have it set up now, you are passing the index of the array into your find method. The first index of an array is always 0, which is why you are getting that error. You could set it up like this:

```
params[:authorization][:contract_ids].each do |id|
```

Comment: No, tried this. When I do this first time I used each, but don't work, so, I started to use each_with_index...

Comment: What issue are you trying to solve by using each_with_index?

Comment: patrickmc I tried the solution of @Corey, and happen other error: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Answer (score 0):

Using this code:

```
Authorization.where(id: params[:authorization][:contract_ids]).update_all(value_solve: [:authorization][:value_solve])
```

Show this error:

```
TypeError in RefinancingsController#new
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```